# The chances of you getting a good job are greater than (my chances) of graduating high school. -- grammaticality

Tags: usage, gerunds, possessives, continuous

- > The chances of you getting a good job are greater than me graduating high school.
- > The chances of you getting a good job are greater than **my chances** of graduating high school.

Are both the sentences grammatically correct?

And if one used, "The chances of your getting a good job are greater than my graduating high school." would that be incorrect?
And is the "greater than my chances of graduating high school" part necessary, or could i just leave that part out like i did in the first sentence?

Comment: See this link: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner

Comment: Native speakers say it both ways. Those who say "my" are going to heaven and those who say "me" will burn in hell.  It's the sad truth.

Comment: @TRomano: So ***my*** being an atheist won't be held against me when I'm queuing up outside the pearly gates to collect my 72 virgins? (They always said ***me*** being an atheist would disqualify me, so it'd be nice to scrape through on a technicality! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Say and do as you please, because if heaven takes its cue from Microsoft Azure, random saints in the queue, like yourself, will be sent to hell, no fault of their own, to reduce the bottleneck at the pearly gates. I believe the theological term is "load balancing".

Comment: @Fumblefingers, the only thing that you need to make **absolutely** sure of  before  you arrive at the pearly gates is that you're not a virgin.

Comment: ... setting aside the gerund accusative/genitive issue, shouldn't there be an "of" before the second clause in the first example? "greater than **of** me graduating high school"